# Left joins all the way with table that has all possible values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's say I have 5 tables: `[AllStates]`, `[FerrariStates]`, `[ToyotaStates]`, `[FordStates]`, `[TelsaStates]`.

Each table is composed of just one column: `state`. `[AllStates]` has all 50 states, the rest may, or may not, have all states.

My result will have exactly 50 rows, and each column will show if there's a Toyota, Ford, Ferrari, Telsa. So the result will have 5 columns.

So if I wanted to show all 50 states, with a 2nd column showing which have Ferraris, then my query would look something like this:

```
select [AllStates].state, [FerrariStates].state from
[AllStates] left join [FerrariStates] on
[AllStates].state = [FerrariStates].state
```

But now I want to include `[TelsaStates]`. Should I `left join` with `[AllStates]` or `[FerrariStates]`? Or should it be an `inner join`?

The same question would apply with `[ToyotaStates]` and `[FordStates]`. Should it be a `left join` or an `inner join`? And with which table should I do the `join`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there is at most one row per state, you want `left join`s to the first table:

```
select a.state,
       (case when f.state is not null then 1 else 0 end) as is_ferrari,
       (case when t.state is not null then 1 else 0 end) as is_tesla,
       . . .
from AllStates a left join
     FerrariStates f
     on f.state = a.state left join
     TeslaStates t
     on t.state = a.state left join
     . . .;
```

The first table is `AllStates`.  That is the population.  The subsequent joins should all be `left join`s back to `AllStates`, to bring in the values from each of the tables.

Notice:

- The use of table aliases so the queries are easier to write and to read.
- The elimination of square braces, which are not necessary.
- The use of a `case` expression to get 0/1 values.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, if it's `AllStates a left join
     FerrariStates f` then why do you flip it with `on f.state = a.state`?

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf . . . I usually put the most recent table alis first in the `join` condition.